# Cannot clone Mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-extension, kiln

I'm having difficulty cloning a repository in Mercurial.
The repository is stored at Kiln on demand, though I'm not sure that makes much difference.
I have a new install of Tortoise HG, which has of course installed the hg command line onto my machine.
When I attempt to clone the repository, I immediately receive the error:

```
abort: The system cannot find the path specified: 'F:\backups\_hgcookies'
Code: 255
```

I don't know where it's getting this path from - there is an 'F' drive on my machine that is completely empty aside from hidden system volume files.

The Kiln Tortoise install contains a couple of plugins bundled with it, including kilnauth, which I assume is using a cookie to store authentication information.
I've looked in the mercurial.ini file, however it contains no mention of this folder or hgcookies - that I can see.

I'm wondering if there's a permissions issue somewhere - I'm in the administrators group on the machine, but am on a company network with quite a bit of lockdown which has caused problems before.

I've not found any similar problems through googling, though it's been difficult to get relevent results with the word 'backup' and 'hgcookies' in my terms!

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the same error using the command line? hg clone .... ?

Comment: Yes I do. I gave it a go in an elevated dos prompt - sorry, did I mention I was on Windows? I suppose the drive letter would imply... It's Vista. To my utter dismay.

Comment: And what version do you have? Last one I presume?

Comment: Tortoise HG 3.2.3 - That's the one currently distributed in the Kiln Tools download.
I have a call scheduled with a friendly support chap over at Fog Creek - I'll report back what we find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this was an issue with the KilnAuth extension. I'm not sure why it decided to store the cookies on the F: drive, but I manually created a 'backups' folder on that drive and that allowed it to store the cookie there with no problems.

I had some help from the FogCreek guys diagnosing this - I have to say I've never experienced such awesome customer service, really. Hats off to those guys!